# What does "This variant falls on 11 transcripts in 3 genes" mean in the output from GnomAD?

Tags: bioinformatics, genomics

The [gnomAD browser](http://gnomad.broadinstitute.org/gene/ENSG00000187634) provides information on variants of genes (in this link, for the SAMD11 gene.)   The report on a particular variant, like [this one](http://gnomad.broadinstitute.org/variant/1-865539-G-A),  includes the information in the header that says (for example): "This variant falls on 5 transcripts in 2 genes."

What does this mean? In particular, how can a variant occur on more than one gene? Isn't such a variant a variant of a particular gene -- SAMD11 in this case?

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, there is another unannotated gene at the same locus, running in the opposite direction as SAMD11.

http://grch37.ensembl.org/Homo_sapiens/Gene/Summary?db=core;g=ENSG00000268179;r=1:865499-865579;t=ENST00000598827

Comment: How can 3 genes turn up?  As in this variant to SAMD1: http://gnomad.broadinstitute.org/variant/19-14198695-C-T

Comment: The SNP is in the upstream region of C19orf67, and the downstream region of PRKACA.  http://grch37.ensembl.org/Homo_sapiens/Variation/Mappings?db=core;r=19:14198195-14199195;v=rs534496627;vdb=variation;vf=67232947